# Do you use the past tense when talking about hypothetical situations?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, subjunctive-mood

Do you use the past tense when using the subjunctive mood to talk about hypothetical situations?

So if I were to write the following sentences, which wordings should I choose?

"If the car were to break down, that would be all I **need/needed**."

"If I were accepted for the role, I would make sure everything I **wrote was/write is** valuable to the audience."

For some reason, I think it's acceptable to use the present tense **"need"** in the first example but necessary to use the past tense **"wrote was"** in the second, but I don't know why.

Comment: I think you can use either of them. Native speakers aren't consistent about this.